# Product images not displaying in magento2

Tags: magento2

magento 2 not loaded correct path for rendering images the correct path of image will be

'bit.ind.in/gogiyacards/pub/media/catalog/product/g/o/gogia-cards-banners-610-x-245-2.jpg'

but it will take

'bit.ind.in/gogiyacards/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/a90544bc52f002dbe888836e62d74d89/g/o/gogia-cards-banners-610-x-245-2.jpg'

It additionally add cache/a90544bc52f002dbe888836e62d74d89

please help me

Answer (score 0):

For non displaying of images, there can be the issue of cache and static files. 
you need to run the below commands after entering the magento root directory through putty.

```
1. php bin/magento cache:flush
2. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Once you run the above commands and all you images are available in the media folder, then refresh the page.

NOTE: You also need to check the right permissions to you `media` folder if the above commands doesn't work.

Comment: it showing the existing product images but when i add new product images   it is not loading again take wrong path as i mention in my query check my link bit.ind.in/gogiyacards

Comment: In magento2, whenever you add images, you need to run the above commands. So standard way is to add all the images in a single shot. Because it will create cache of all the images and from cache the magento serve's the required images. So if you add images, then u need to run the above 2 commands all the time. If the above answer helps, it would be great if you accept and upmark it. so that it will be helpful to others too..